# .htaccess for post id

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have PHP file .htaccess :

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?user=$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/home/.*$ index.php [QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/friends$ friends.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)/([a-z-]+) post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Now I want the url post to be like this :

```
http://example.com/yoana/post/id_post
```

I tried with that rule above, but it is still not working.

The error is :

```
Object not found!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What rule must match the given url?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)/([a-z-]+) post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]

Comment: I don't see that given url started with `post`, it starts with `yoana`. Btw, why did you put that many `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: for yoana, it have another function for example : example.com/yoana. For post example.com/yoana/post/id_post <-- that I need the rule function

Comment: So? What is your question about then?

Comment: Now I want the url post to be like this :

http://example.com/yoana/post/id_post

I tried with that rule above, but it still not working.

Comment: The rule above does not match it because your url starts with `yoana` and your rule starts with `post`. Not to say that the whole url structure is different from the rule structure.

Comment: So, do you have any suggestion for that?

Comment: For what? They do not match because they are different. What is your question?

Comment: Assume it's like twitter... example, when you open twitter.com/david, it will open the profile right? and when we want to open his tweet : https://twitter.com/David/status/541957243051450368.

Comment: Okay. So what is your question?

Comment: How can I set that like a twitter?

Comment: You can write some rule that matches that url

Comment: Oh thanks. That's an awesome answer. Great man. If you can't or don't know how to answer just tell. I will let you know when I got the answer.

Comment: You want someone to do that for you and you don't want to learn. That's not how stackoverflow work.

Comment: I post my code, then I describe the details and I explain it to you and now what is wrong with that? At least you can tell me where and what need to do???

Comment: You probably need to try learning how `mod_rewrite` works and how to create regex rules for it.